# Pass Variable to Badge Text in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have built an extension that grabs some info from a div on a page and stores it in a variable called  'div'. I now need to pass that value into my background.js file so that I can update the badge to reflect the text in that variable.

I have read through the sendMessage info but every time I add the line of code to my page it seems to break the extension so I am definitely doing something wrong.

Here is the code without the setBadgeText info in it (currently functioning).

getQueue.js

```
var myVar = null;
setFunction();

function setFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(function () {myTimer();}, 10000);
}

function myTimer() {
var THRESHOLD = 0;
var div = document.getElementById("sessions_queued_now_row-000");
var num = parseInt(div.innerText);

// Here is where I want to pass div to background.js to update the badge text

if (num >= THRESHOLD) {
    // I do a bunch of stuff here       
}


}
```

My background.js file isnt doing much right now but opening up a URL in a new tab.

I am looking for what I need to add to both the getQueue.js file and also the background.js file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

The documentation is good on this topic; however, a short overview:

1. Extension page<sup>1</sup> can register a listener for a `chrome.runtime.onMessage` event.
2. The content script calls `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to broadcast a **JSON-serializable** message to all extension pages in its parent extension.

<sup>1</sup> See this [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) for a better definition of "extension page"

I expressly emphasized "JSON-serializable", because an `HTMLElement` is **not** serializable. You need to extract the properties you need (like `innerText`) before sending.

```
// Background script

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  // It is recommended to add a message type so your code
  //   can be ready for more types of messages in the future
  switch(message.type) {
    case "updateBadge":
      // Do stuff with message.data
      break;
    default:
      console.warn("Unrecognized message type: " + message.type);
      break;
  }
});

// Content script

var div = document.getElementById("sessions_queued_now_row-000");
var data = { text : div.innerText /*, something else?*/ };
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "updateBadge", data: data });
```