# How can I get different badge value for every tab on chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to do something like adblock does. Adblock counts number of "ads" and update badge value. For now, I tried to do something with 'background pages', but they are run only one time and badge value is the same for all tabs. I can't use browser action popup.html, because it triggers only after the click. 
So I need something which *takes current tab, is able to read current DOM of tab and after all update badge value*. But also after I click on different tab I need to compute new badge value. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552924/pass-variable-to-badge-text-in-chrome-extension could be the answer to your question!

Answer (score 16):

The badge text is stored for each tab independently provided you specify tabId parameter, you don't have to update it manually after the user switches tabs if you already have set the value.

So if your extension processes the pages immediately after loading, call `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText` once. You can do it e.g. by sending a message from your content script to your background/event page which will invoke `setBadgeText` with the sender tab's id (this parameter is what makes the text unique to a tab).

content script:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({badgeText: "123"});
```

background/event script:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.badgeText != null) {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
      tabId: sender.tab.id,
      text: message.badgeText,
    }, () => chrome.runtime.lastError); // ignore errors due to closed/prerendered tabs
  }
});
```

Comment: are you sure the badge text is stored for each tab? not according to my experience

Comment: [Provided](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText) you specify `tabId` parameter. I've added a more obvious clarification to the answer.

Comment: Doesn't `chrome.tabs.get` just get what you already have as `sender.tab`? And how can I reproduce the "prerendered tab" case?

Comment: Yes it does and the point was to confirm the tab exists and is visible. Anyway get() is no longer needed in Chrome 67+ because they added callbacks to browserAction methods, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to the [Chrome tab events](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) in your background/event page. The following code helped me to solve the same problem:

```
// fires when tab is updated
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(updateBadge);

// fires when active tab changes
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(updateBadge);

function updateBadge() {
  // get active tab on current window
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {
    // the return value is an array
    var activeTab = arrayOfTabs[0];
    if (!activeTab) return;
    // compute number for badge for current tab's url
    var count = getCount(activeTab.url);
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
      text: count.toString()
    });
  });
}

function getCount(currentUrl) {
  // your logic, e.g., return 42
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an "onActiveChanged" listener and call your updateBadge function and pass the tabId. Hope it helped.

```js
chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    updateBadge(tabId);
});

function updateBadge(tabId) {
...
}
```