# chrome.runtime.onMessage listener is never fired

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to set a badge text specific for each tab in Chrome.

I've followed along with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32168534/8126260 to do so, though the `chrome.runtime.onMessage` event handler is never being fired.

```
// tab specific badges https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168449/how-can-i-get-different-badge-value-for-every-tab-on-chrome
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log('runtime message');
  if (message.badgeText) {
    console.log('runtime message with badge text');
      chrome.tabs.get(sender.tab.id, function(tab) {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
              return; // the prerendered tab has been nuked, happens in omnibox search
          }
          if (tab.index >= 0) { // tab is visible
              chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({tabId:tab.id, text:message.badgeText});
              console.log('set message');
          } else { // prerendered tab, invisible yet, happens quite rarely
              var tabId = sender.tab.id, text = message.badgeText;
              chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function update(details) {
                  if (details.tabId == tabId) {
                      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({tabId: tabId, text: text});
                      chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.removeListener(update);
                  }
              });
          }
      });
  }
});

// block outgoing requests for help widgets
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
              function(details) {
                //send message

                console.log('send message');
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({badgeText: "HELP"});

                  if (isDisabled) {
                    return { cancel: false } // this should return from the function (details) level
                  } else {
                    return { cancel: true }
                  }
              },
              {urls: [
                "a bunch of urls irrelevant to this question"
              ]},
              ["blocking"]);
```

(the entire source code is on https://github.com/bcye/Hello-Goodbye)

Looking into the console of my background script, send message appears, meaning that `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({badgeText: "HELP"});` should have been executed.

None of the console.log statements in the onMessage listener get executed though.

Comment: Are you sending the message to the listener in the background script? That won't work, the target should be a different page. Within the same page you can use the standard js methods like direct function invocation or a custom event subscriber/emitter.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes I'm sending them from the background.js file. Though how could I  get the tab id, since with direct function invocation, I wouldn't get the sender object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, as @wOxxOm said this is impossible.

Though webRequest passes a tabId in the details dictionary.
This can be used to replicate that.